# Get values from array that is type of PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the values from `PSCustomObject` and can't find the right way.

```
PS: $val
  entry1 : @{order=10; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}
  entry2 : @{order=20; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}
  entry3 : @{order=30; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}

PS: $val.GetType()
  IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType
  -------- -------- ----     --------
  True     True     Object[] System.Array

PS: $val[0]
  entry1 : @{order=10; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}
  entry2 : @{order=20; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}
  entry3 : @{order=30; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}

PS: $val[0].GetType()
  IsPublic IsSerial Name           BaseType
  -------- -------- ----           --------
  True     False    PSCustomObject System.Object
```

All the ways I've tried, I'm always getting the same result. I've tried to get the values from `$val.PSObject` but with no luck

UPDATE:

```
$val | gm
Name              MemberType   Definition
----              ----------   ----------
Equals            Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method       type GetType()
ToString          Method       string ToString()
entry1            NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject entry1=@{order=10; isConditionalDeploy=1;
entry2            NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject entry2=@{order=20; isConditionalDeploy=1; 
entry3            NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject entry3=@{order=30; isConditionalDeploy=1;
```

Comment: how did you  create the $Val array? the lines you show don't look like what i would expect from an array of PSCustomObjects. for instance, where did the `entry1 :` come from?

Comment: Reading from json with following command: `Get-Content  $Path | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: what does `$val | gm` return?

Comment: Try `$val.entry1`

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - please post the JSON. i can't tell what your data really is from what you  have posted. [*blush*]

Comment: I can access the needed data by using `$val.entry1` however how to get the name (entry1)

Answer (score 2):

In order to list all of the property names, run the following:

```
$val.psobject.properties.name
```

In order to list all of the property values, run the following:

```
$val.psobject.properties.value
```

Since `$val.psobject.properties.name` and `$val.psobject.properties.name` are arrays, their elements are accessible by an index. So if you wanted the first name and first value, they can be accessed by `$val.psobject.properties.name[0]` and `$val.psobject.properties.value[0]`.

If you already know the property names and just want values, you can access values by following what Theo suggested.

I have made a JSON file and named it json.json. It contains the following:

```
{
"entry1":
    {
        "order":"10",
        "isConditionalDeploy":"1",
        "isDropExtendedProperties":"0"
    },
"entry2":
    {
        "order":"20",
        "isConditionalDeploy":"1",
        "isDropExtendedProperties":"0"
    }
}
```

The following results in creating a `$val` variable that looks like yours:

```
$val = Get-Content json.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$val | fl

entry1 : @{order=10; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}
entry2 : @{order=20; isConditionalDeploy=1; isDropExtendedProperties=0}

$val | gm

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

    Name        MemberType   Definition
    ----        ----------   ----------
    Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
    GetType     Method       type GetType()
    ToString    Method       string ToString()
    entry1      NoteProperty Object[] entry1=System.Object[]
    entry2      NoteProperty Object[] entry2=System.Object[]
```

With doing all of the above, my property name and value retrieval works as I have suggested. Can you please provide your JSON file contents?

Comment: $val.psobject.properties.name gives Count,Length,LongLength,Rank,SyncRoot,IsReadOnly,IsFixedSize,IsSynchronized

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to access the values, this should work:

```
$json = '{
"entry1":
    {
        "order":"10",
        "isConditionalDeploy":"1",
        "isDropExtendedProperties":"0"
    },
"entry2":
    {
        "order":"20",
        "isConditionalDeploy":"1",
        "isDropExtendedProperties":"0"
    }
}'

$val = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$val | ForEach-Object {
    $_.PSObject.Properties.Value
}
```

---

### Output

```
order isConditionalDeploy isDropExtendedProperties
----- ------------------- ------------------------
10    1                   0
20    1                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of PSCustomObject, you should be able to see the values by piping the array to Format-List or Format-Table.